# I'm trying to do a query and it gives parse error

Tags: php, mysql

When i do a query it says:

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in *****/postchange.php on line 125"
```

My query is:

**PHP**:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($id > 1){
  mysql_query("UPDATE `post` SET userid = 16 WHERE postid = "$id)
  or die(mysql_error());
  echo '...Done';
} else {
  echo 'Invalid post.';
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `.` between your string and variable. It's necessary to concatenate into a single string. It should be:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `post` SET userid = 16 WHERE postid = " . $id)
or die(mysql_error());
```

Although really you should be using [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDOs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Additionally, your query is extremely susceptible to SQL Injections. You need to sanitize the $_GET['p'] before entering it into the database. At the very least, use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: thanks that worked. i'll look into the mysqli stuff

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php mysql_query("UPDATE `post` SET `userid`='16' WHERE `postid`=".$id); ?>
```